# Why I can't edit posts on meta?

Tags: discussion, review, suggested-edits, meta

Why I can't edit posts on meta?

I first thought that because I am a $<2000$ user then my edits will shown in suggested edit reviews and I thought there is no where to review suggested edit in meta. But I recently saw that there is. Now why I can't edit? If I can't edit then what is suggested edit review used to?

Comment: meta.SE: [Per-site metas don't have ability of suggested-edits](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78223/per-site-metas-dont-have-ability-of-suggested-edits) and [Why can't I suggest edits on SE meta sites?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87890/why-cant-i-suggest-edits-on-se-meta-sites)

Comment: In the [suggested edit review history on meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/history) I see only edit suggestions for tag-wikis, here is [one example](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/393). Only 20k+ users can [edit tag-wikis without needing approval](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/trusted-user). So my guess would be that these are only suggested edits possible on meta, but I do not have some official documentation to confirm this.

Comment: I think there are also comminucaty wikis I can edit them.

Comment: You mean community wiki. IIRC in the case of community wiki, you can simply edit them, the edit does not go through the review. More info on community wikis can be found [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/tags/community-wiki/info).

Comment: I think everyone, at least, be able to do edit suggestions, in which case I would definitely suggest you correct your grammar mistake in the title.